# Displaying separated multi-line text fields

Tags: c#, html, razor

The following code grabs the HTML-encoded, multi-line content of a text field. It then splits the content on line breaks, and finally displays it with commas as separators.

I would like to have this code reviewed to see if there is a simpler way to grab the string, split and display it.

*Note* - I hated the idea of writing 2 collection iterations, but I found if a user in the CMS entered one line of real data, and then a couple of empty line breaks, it would throw the array length off and display a comma on a single item e.g. output should look like this :

- **Correct**: Allowed Uses: example 1 | Allowed Uses: example 1, example 2
- **Incorrect**: Allowed Uses: example 1, | Allowed Uses: example 1, example 2,

```razor
  var retailBreaks = umbraco.library.ReplaceLineBreaks(Model.landAllowedUses);
  string[] retailBreaksSplit = retailBreaks.Split(new string[] { "<br/>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  int breaksLength = 0;
  List<String> repeatableProperty = new List<String>();
  foreach (string s in retailBreaksSplit)
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
       {
         repeatableProperty.Add(s);
       }
  }
 breaksLength = repeatableProperty.Count();

 <div>
    <strong>Allowed Uses:</strong>

    @foreach (string s in repeatableProperty)
    {
     <span class="comma-list">@s.Trim()@((breaksLength > 1 && repeatableProperty.Last<string>() != s) ? ", " : string.Empty)  </span>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a string replace to swap the html breaks for commas, then trim the end to remove any extra commas:

```
retailBreaks.Replace("<br/>",",").TrimEnd(',')
```

Comment: Love the simplicity!

Answer (score 2):

You already have got a nice and simple solution from @GavinCoates so I only would like to add a couple of comments about your code for your future coding experience.

- You should consequently use either full types for your variables or the `var` keyword. In your code the `var` would greatly improve the readabilty as all types are obvious here and don't need to declared twice:

  ```
  var retailBreaks = umbraco.library.ReplaceLineBreaks(Model.landAllowedUses);
  var retailBreaksSplit = retailBreaks.Split(new string[] { "<br/>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  var breaksLength = 0;
  var repeatableProperty = new List<String>();
  ```
- The same applies to the `foreach`-loops:

  ```
  foreach (var s in retailBreaksSplit)
  ```
- You started using good variable names but didn't continue in your loops. This would look and read mutch better:

  ```
  foreach (var retailBreak in retailBreaksSplit)
  ```
- If you have collections or lists etc. you should name the variables using plural form to indicate it's more then one element. This would be a better name for the list:

  ```
  var repeatableProperties = new List<String>();
  ```
- The final thing I would change is the last loop. I would create a helper variable for the text instead of putting it inside the span. *It's been long time since I last coded with `ASP.NET` so please forgive me if I got the syntax wrong.*

  ```
  @foreach (var repeatableProperty in repeatableProperties)
  {
       var text = @((breaksLength > 1 && repeatableProperty.Last<string>() != s) ? ", " : string.Empty);
       <span class="comma-list">@s.Trim()@text </span>
  }
  ```